# Cordova, Ionic3: Error: exec proxy not found for :: GooglePlus :: login

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am trying to go Google plus Auth with Ionic 3/Cordova app. I am using [this tutorial](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#6-usage))

in order to use google Auth.

code example

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GooglePlus } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    login(){

        GooglePlus.login({
          'webClientId': 'my web client id'
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

    logout(){

        GooglePlus.logout().then(() => {
            console.log("logged out");
        });

    }

}
```

html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>
      Google GCal
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <button ion-button full (click)="login()">Login</button>

    <button ion-button full (click)="logout()">Logout</button>

</ion-content>
```

on the screen when i press login I am getting this error below
**Error: exec proxy not found for :: GooglePlus :: login Missing Command**

I've used iOS emulator, and Ionic lab in order to test but no cigar. Any help is appreacited

Comment: anyone???? :D :D :D

Comment: You must sign apk for testing google plus